# Extend a library service and block access to it

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I am using CDK library in my project. I import it in the dependencies of package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.2",
}
```

I then extended the CDK Overlay service with my custom service like this:

```
export class MyOverlayService extends Overlay { ... }
```

Now, I want the users to *only* be able to use the custom MyOverlayService and have no access to the native Overlay service.

I tried adding it to the app.module.ts providers:

```
{
      provide: Overlay,
      useClass: MyOverlayService
}
```

but the user can still use the native service, which is not what I want.

Any idea?